# How to avoid catching the HTTP OPTIONS request in the express.js auth middleware

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, token

Okay I have a backend API built in express.js that responds to a SPA built in AngularJS. I am using token authentication to verify the access of clients to fetch certain resources.

The way I check on wether the incoming request from the front-end has an Authorization header containing the Bearer token or not is in an authentication middleware I made myself in express.js.

The problem is that AngularJS sends a preflight OPTIONS reuqest before the actual get request and the OPTIONS one is the first thing caught by the middleware causing it to refuse the request since it doesn't have a Bearer token in it and it halts the execution.

The question is how to avoid catching this annoying OPTIONS request in my Authentication middleware and just catch the actual get request which contains a bearer token authorization.

This is the code of the http request sent from my angularJS app

```
return $http(
            {
                method: 'GET',
                url:  API_URL,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'faketoken'
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: The request method is known. Skip the authentication routine if it's OPTIONS.

Comment: Thanks! This worked fine but I was wondering if this OPTIONS request is at all necessary to send in the first place!

Comment: The options request is necessary. In case of cross origin requests, the preflight request is sent automatically prior to the main request in order to determine whether the server allows requests from the given origin. The response to the options request must contain access-control related headers. Should there be no options request, or no response to that, the main request will fail.

Comment: ahaa this makes sense now! thanks

Answer (score 0):

do these packets go to a L3 Ip address? or a L2 protocols?

Comment: I am not sure you get the context of my question right